# Excecuting a Powershell script within a SSIS package

Tags: powershell, ssis

The Powershell script goes to a website, grab some information and writes it on a flat file.
If I run the script within Powershell it works perfectly, but when I run it from SQL Server Agent, it fails.
I have already given read/write permisions in the server to the SQL Server Agent user who runs the package.
I also have tried creating a Step Type: PowerShell and just run the script from within the job; Operating system (CmdExec) excecuting powershell comand with the file name as an argument; Operating system (CmdExec) running a batch file which calls the Powershell script.

This is the powershell script:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $false
$ie.Navigate("https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/fpddir.txt")
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button") | where-object {$_.value -eq "Agree"}
If($Link){
    $Link.click()
}
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}
$destination = ".\FDRTestFile\FDRFile.txt"
$content = (@($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("pre"))[0].innerText | Out-
File $destination)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)
Remove-Variable ie
```

I'm getting this error when the job finishes:

> New-Object : Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID   {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to   the following error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT:   0x80004005 (E_FAIL)).  At D:\SSIS\FDR\DownloadFDRFile.ps1:1 char:7  + $ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'  +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object] COMExcept      ion      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentifiedMicrosoft.PowerShell.Comman      ds.NewObjectCommandProperty 'Visible' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is   settable.  At D:\SSIS\FDR\DownloadFDRFile.ps1:3 char:1  + $ie.Visible= $true  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [] RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundYou cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At D:\SSIS\FDR\DownloadFDRFile.ps1:4 char:1  + $ie.Navigate("https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/fpddir.txt")  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [] RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At D:\SSIS\FDR\DownloadFDRFile.ps1:8 char:1  + $Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button") | where-object {$_.value   -eq " ...  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [] RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At D:\SSIS\FDR\DownloadFDRFile.ps1:17 char:15  + $content = (@($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("pre"))[0].innerText |   Out-File  ...  +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [] RuntimeException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     Exception calling "ReleaseComObject" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference   not set to an instance of an object."  At D:\SSIS\FDR\DownloadFDRFile.ps1:18 char:1  + [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie)  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [] MethodInvocationException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException     Remove-Variable : Cannot find a variable with name 'ie'.  At D:\SSIS\FDR\DownloadFDRFile.ps1:19 char:1  + Remove-Variable ie  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ie:String) [Remove-Variable] I      temNotFoundException      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFoundMicrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.R      emoveVariableCommand.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.,00:00:02,0,0,,,,0

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I suggest you log in to the SQL as the SQL Agent account, start IE, and see if there is any IE setup that you need to go through first. (i.e. setting security etc.) My first though is that it's an intentional security block.

Comment: Make sure your "Run As" account usually SQL Agent has access to run Powershell. If it doesn't have the DBA create a proxy to use that can run Powershell. This "Run As" is chosen at the step level.